# Cant call .json on array of responses

Tags: javascript

I am practicing async await, and I have an array that is an array of responses to which i think i have to call .json() to parse the response, but i keep getting errors, any idea how can i resolve those responses to that i get the json im trying to get?

This is the code you can see at the bottom this is the problematic line:
 `return responses.map( r => r.json())`

here id a codepen: https://codepen.io/giorgiomartini/pen/OJJzKoM?editors=1011
and this is all the code:

```
const TITLE = 'Princess Mononoke'

async function getMoro(url) {
  const moviesResponse = await fetch(url)
  const movies = await moviesResponse.json()
  const movie = movies.find(movie => movie.title = TITLE)
  const speciesLink = movie.species[0]
  const speciesResponse = await fetch(speciesLink)
  const specie = await speciesResponse.json()
  const people = specie.people
  const PromisesOfResponsesOfPeopleUrls = people.map(async peopleUrl => {
    return await fetch(peopleUrl)
  })

  const responses = Promise.all(PromisesOfResponsesOfPeopleUrls)



  return responses.map( r => r.json())
}

getMoro('https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films')
  .then(c => console.log('c: ', c))
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: `Promise.all` returns a promise.

Comment: `movies.find(movie => movie.title = TITLE)` is an assignment and not an equality check use `==` or `===`

Comment: Is there a reason for the separate `.map(r => r.json())` call? Why not `fetch(peopleUrl).then(response => response.json())` ?